# Как получить данные из mongoDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, mongodb

Как получить данные из mongoDB? Только знакомлюсь с mongodb да и вообще в принципе с бэком. Не могу понять как мне предавать данные из монго в мой проект? Запустил по документации что то типа "Сервера" на node.js. С бд связь есть, добавляю, обновляю, вывожу в консоль значения из таблицы. А вот как передать в проект не знаю.

Пробовал посылать запрос, с помощью fetch. получаю ошибку (Запрос из постороннего источника заблокирован: Политика одного источника запрещает чтение удаленного ресурса на http://localhost:27017/users. (Причина: отсутствует заголовок CORS «Access-Control-Allow-Origin»))

Скиньте сылки на доки или видео где объясняют по простому, плиз. Ну или помогите советом

```js
// COMPONENT
methods: {
  addToApi() {
    let newUser = {
      name: this.User.name,
      secondname: this.User.secondname,
    };
    console.log(newUser);

    fetch('http://localhost:27017/users')
      .then(response => response.text())
      .then((result) => {
        console.log('result: ' + result);
      })

  }
}

//SERVER   
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const assert = require('assert');

// Connection URL
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';

// Database Name
const dbName = 'main-shop';

// Create a new MongoClient
const client = new MongoClient(url, {
  useUnifiedTopology: true
});

// Use connect method to connect to the Server
client.connect(function (err) {
  assert.equal(null, err);
  console.log("Connected successfully to server");

  const db = client.db(dbName);

  findUsers(db, function () {
    client.close();
  });
});
```

```html
<form v-on:submit.prevent="addToApi">
  <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Nmae" v-model="User.name">
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="secondname" placeholder="Second Name" v-model="User.secondname">
  <br>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://youtu.be/7QD1j3fulOc

аут оф документасьён солюшн....... мин чар мин чар мин чар рестрикт

Answer (score 1):

на сервере обрабатывай запрос

```
const app = express();
app.post("/user/signup", UserController.create);
```

и в контролере выполняй работу с бд

```
class UserController {
   create = (req, res) => {
    ...
   }
}
```